# Ansible - how to add selected attributes from dict variable into a template?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create a report from a job. Thinking about creating a local file and emailing it. But I don't know how I can get the needed data from this variable.

This is the output of the test var

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "test": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": true,
        "msg": "One or more items failed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "elapsed": 4.0650629,
                "failed": true,
                "item": "prdrimaknmcs01.perceptive.cloud",
                "msg": "timeout while waiting for prdrimaknmcs01.perceptive.cloud:9091 to start listening",
                "wait_attempts": 2
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "elapsed": 4.0600610999999995,
                "failed": true,
                "item": "prdrimaknmcs02.perceptive.cloud",
                "msg": "timeout while waiting for prdrimaknmcs02.perceptive.cloud:9091 to start listening",
                "wait_attempts": 2
            }
        ],
        "skipped": false
    }
}
```

I need to add both items and messages into my template file. The problem is that this specific var is for 2 tests but it can be any number of tests from 1 to 10. So I thought about using "for"  in a variable substitution in my template. Similar to this. Cannot make it work.

```
    {% for rslts in test %}
Message: {{ test.results.msg }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `{% for result in test.results %}Message: {{ result.msg }}{% endfor %}`. Your list is under `test.results`.

Comment: Please consider banning "not working" (and all alike expressions) from your vocabulary on Q&A sites like SO (at least without giving any further detailed information). [It does not accurately describe your problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test.results` is a list, not `test`, so your loop must look like this:

```
{% for rslt in test.results %}
Message: {{ rslt.msg }}
{% endfor %}
```

You iterate over the entries of `test.results` and have them available in the loop in `rslt`, so you must then access the respective value via `rslt.msg`.

Comment: thanks... just realized that :)